# An isomorphism between $\mathbb R^2$ and the space of polynomials of degree at most $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Let $V$ be the vector space of real-valued polynomials $p(x)$ of degree at most $1$. Prove that   the map
> $$T:V\to\mathbb R^2,\quad  p \mapsto [p(1), p(2)]$$
> is an isomorphism.

#### Progress

For an isomorphism, the kernel must contain the zero vector. I tried saying $p(x) = a_0+a_1x$ and then finding $p(1)$ and $p(2)$ but it doesn't seem to be doing anything for me.

Comment: Hey David,yes for an isomorphism the kernel contains the zero vector. 

I tried saying p(x) = a[sub]0[/sub] + a[sub]1[/sub]x and then finding p(1) and p(2) but it doesn't seem to be doing anything for me because I'm unsure on how to answer.

Comment: There is **way** more to an isomorphism than having a kernel which contains the zero vector.

Comment: It is one to one and admits an inverse also?

Comment: You have to argue that $T$ is linear and a bijection. See my post for how I argue linearity. That is, $T(ca + b) = cT(a) + T(b)$, where $a, b$ are polynomials of degree at most $1$.

Answer (score 2):

To show isomorphism, you have to show the transformation is a bijection where addition and scalar multiplication are preserved.

So consider $T(ax + b) = T(cx + d)$. Then $(a, b) = (c, d) \implies a = c$ and $b = d$. So we have that $T$ is one-to-one. To show onto, consider $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Such a polynomial in $P_{1}(\mathbb{R})$ is $ax + b$. And so $T$ is onto.

Now we show additivity is preserved: $T(p(x) + q(x)) = T(ax + b + cx + d) = T((a+c)x + b + d) = (a + c, b + d) = (a, b) + (c, d) = T(ax + b) + T(cx + d)$

To show scalar multiplication is preserved: $T(3(ax + b)) = T(3ax + 3b) = (3a, 3b) = 3(a, b) = 3T(ax + b)$.

And so $T$ is an isomorphism.

Note: You can show preservation of addition and multiplication in one step, and many people do so.

Also, an alternative to showing that the mapping is bijective is to show that $ker(T) = 0$, or that $T$ is of full rank. You can do this by constructing a transformation matrix from $T$ on the standard basis of $P_{1}(\mathbb{R})$. So $T(x) = (1, 0)$ and $T(1) = (0, 1)$. And so $det [T(x) T(1)] = 1$, and so $T$ is of full rank. Thus, $T$ is bijective. Then you just have to argue linearity.

Comment: Thanks for the clear instructions, it really helped!

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Note you can write p as $p=ax+b$ then the image can be written as $v=(a+b, 2a+b)$, when $v=(0,0)$ we can directly get $a=b=0$ which means if and only if $p=0$, there can be $v=0$.
So the kernel is {0}.

Comment: My Pleasure~: )